# Assign the filename to the imported array in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, path, glob

I have folder which includes many csv files namely a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2, b_1, b_2....

I want to import each csv file as their names. For example

a_1 = pd.read_csv("a_1.csv")

a_2 = pd.read_csv("a_2.csv")

In order to do that:

```
path = r"C:\Users\Desktop\sync\work\all_csvs"
csv_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

colname=['time', 'var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3', 'var_4', 'var_5'] 
os.path.basename(csv_files[0]).split(".")[0] = pd.read_csv(csv_files[0], names=colname ,header=None)
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way to make the system dynamic? I will use it in the for loop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question isn't very clear: How should your expected output exactly look like?

Comment: a_1 = pd.read_csv("a_1.csv"),

a_2 = pd.read_csv("a_2.csv"), etc

Comment: So you want a variable for each dataframe that is named like the corresponding file? That doesn't sound like a good idea. Better do something like in the answer (collect the dataframes in a dictionary with the filenames as keys). (If you really want to do it, then use something like `globals()[filename] = pd.read_csv(filename)` in a loop over the `glob` results - but that's not a good idea.)

Comment: No, that's not a good idea, use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the list of files in `csv_files`, loop through the list to import all of the files.

```
files = {}

for file in csv_files:
    files[file] = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, file), ....)
```

We use `os.path.join` to generate the absolute path for the file.

This will store all the imported csv files into the `files` dictionary with keys as the name of the file.